# How to use Dagger 2 effectively with MVVM and Clean Architecture a multi module Android project

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dagger-2, clean-architecture

I have a multi-module project that follows Clean Architecture principles. I have app, presentation, domain, data and remote modules. I am also using Android Architecture Components and apply MVVM in the presentation layer.

A simple `ViewModel` class looks like this

```
class SignUpViewModel @Inject internal constructor(
    private val signUpInfoMapper: Mapper<SignUpInfo, SignUpInfoEntity>,
    private val signUpTask: SignUpTask
) : ViewModel() {

    // LiveData and methods
}
```

Every `ViewModel` has a dependency on a task(use-case)from the domain module and one or more mapper. Every use-case has a dependency on a repository class from the data module. Every repository class has a dependency on the API from the remote module. So there are chains of dependencies.

I am injecting the ViewModels as below and the `ViewModelModule` belongs to `Singleton` `AppCpmponent`.

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(SignUpViewModel::class)
    internal abstract fun signUpViewModel(viewModel: SignUpViewModel): ViewModel
}

@Target(
    AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER
)
@kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
internal annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)
```

At the moment every `ViewModel` dependency and sub-dependencies annotated with `Singleton` scope. It works but annotating all these classes as `Singleton` might not be a good idea as the project is growing and the number of singleton classes that will live for the entire life cycle of the app is increasing. So I thought that having a different Dagger 2 component for each feature and necessary modules with a different scope would solve the problem but ViewModels can't be annotated with feature scopes.

I wonder what is the best practice to apply dependency injection via Dagger 2 in a multi-module project with MVVM and Clean Architecture.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ey how did you share your domain models between modules ? do you have a good example ?

Comment: I do not share domain models. Each layer has its own models and mapper classes to transform them. However, sometimes this is overkill. In that case, you can create an additional "core" module, add data models to that layer and share this module between all the layers.

Comment: How did this kind of architecture work for you in your project? ... wich was the biggest problem to have each feature in a new module ? . I am panning to do the same as you . and I found I would need to have sometimes the same models in each feature . any advice for this kind of architecture?

Comment: If you have a small project, I would not recommend using it. Usually, the problem with this architecture is that you have to deal with too much boilerplate.

Comment: is not a small project .